# kml not rendering properly on google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, cache-control

I have set up kml on google maps. problem is when user starts to zoom in and out on specific region of the world and pan the map at same time the kml loads but is transparent. If you know where it is you can still click on it but you cannot see it.

You can test by http://www.spectrumgeo.com/seismic-data-library/multi-client-library/interactive-map if you browse to Australia part of the world and zoom in an out and pan around the continent, problem will occur. This happens when user does this fast.

htaccess under map dir

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
```

htaccess under root dir

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

BrowserMatch MSIE ie
Header set X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie

# Disable Directory Browsing
Options All -Indexes

#needed for knowledge map
Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

#ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images




#http://crunchify.com/how-to-speed-up-wordpress-leveraging-browser-caching-via-htaccess/
Header unset Pragma
Header unset ETag
FileETag None



<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"

# 1day
#    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 years"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: can this be moved to Geographic Information Systems instead of downvoting please

Answer (score 1):

Zooming in to your map around Australia it looks like there's a lot of features being shown.  I suspect your KML file is getting pretty close to the [limits](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) of what Google will render server-side... or at least what can be rendered quickly.

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Render the KML into transparent tiles on your server and use an image overlays to render those static tiles instead of KMLLayer.
2. Render the KML client side.  GeoJSON is probably going to be easier to parse, but the features look like lines and polygons which you could try rendering natively in the JavaScript API.  The [`google.maps.Data`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson) layer may be a good starting point if you convert the KML to JSON.

If using KMLLayer is your only option, ensuring that you set good HTTP caching headers and are serving your KML really quickly can help minimize any loading delays.

Comment: are there any examples i can look at you know of dor number 1. and 2.? can you tell me what i need to add to htaccess? question updated with htaccess contents.  i dont think i can do option 1 as i need the lines and polygons to be clickable

Comment: I added a link to my answer discussing how you could easily render GeoJSON.  I'm not sure the best way to convert your KML to that format.

If your features need to be clickable, I agree #1 isn't a very good option.  You could do it, but it'd be hard.